# the flutter audio wiveforms package does not display waveforms

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio-recording, audiowaveform

I hope you are well, I have a big problem with the flutter audio waveforms package, indeed I want to display the waveforms of my voice files in a folder, but they are not displayed and when I display the value of `playerController.bufferData` I get a null, please how can I manage this problem, I have already spent days on it.
Sincerely
below are my classes

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:audio_recorder/AudioWaveFormsWidget.dart';
import 'package:audio_waveforms/audio_waveforms.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Audio Recorder',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Audio Recorder'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //late final PlayerController playerController1;
  final record = Record();
  int _recordDuration = 0;
  Timer? _timer;
  RecordState _recordState = RecordState.stop;
  StreamSubscription<RecordState>? _recordSub;
  final List<File> _audioFile = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Listening record state
    _recordSub = record.onStateChanged().listen((recordState) {
      setState(() => _recordState = recordState);
    });

    initCheckPermission();
    setState(() {
      initFileInDir();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _recordSub?.cancel();
    record.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future initCheckPermission() async {
    final statusMicrophone = await Permission.microphone.request();
    final statusStorage = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (statusMicrophone != PermissionStatus.granted ||
        statusStorage != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await Permission.microphone.request();
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      setState(() => _recordDuration++);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildText() {
    if (_recordState != RecordState.stop) {
      return _buildTimer();
    }

    return const Text("Waiting to record");
  }

  String _formatNumber(int number) {
    String numberStr = number.toString();
    if (number < 10) {
      numberStr = '0$numberStr';
    }

    return numberStr;
  }

  Widget _buildTimer() {
    final String minutes = _formatNumber(_recordDuration ~/ 60);
    final String seconds = _formatNumber(_recordDuration % 60);

    return Text(
      '$minutes : $seconds',
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    );
  }

  Future<Directory> _getDir() async {
    //Check platform and adjust settings
    final tempDir = Platform.isAndroid
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
        : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Directory finalPath;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      String buildDir =
          tempDir!.path.replaceFirst("/data/", "/media/").split("files").first;
      buildDir += "AudioRecorder"; // Plus ajout du nom de l'application
      return finalPath = await Directory(buildDir).create(recursive: true);
    } else {
      return finalPath = await Directory(tempDir!.path).create(recursive: true);
    }
  }

  void initFileInDir() async {
    Directory finalPath = await _getDir();

    var exists = await finalPath.exists();
    if (exists) {
      finalPath.list(recursive: false).forEach((element) {
        File file = File(element.path);
        _audioFile.add(file);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildStopAndPlayIcon() {
    if (_recordState != RecordState.stop) {
      return const Icon(Icons.stop);
    } else {
      return const Icon(Icons.mic);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _start() async {
    Directory finalPath = await _getDir();

    //Start recording
    await record.start(
        path: '${finalPath.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.m4a',
        encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc, // by default
        bitRate: 128000, // by default
        samplingRate: 44100);
    _recordDuration = 0;

    _startTimer();
  }

  Future<File?> _stop() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _recordDuration = 0;

    final path = await record.stop();
    File? file;
    if (path != null) {
      file = File(path);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("--------------------------$path");
      }
    }
    return file;
  }

  Future<void> _pause() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    await record.pause();
  }

  Future<void> _resume() async {
    _startTimer();
    await record.resume();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            LimitedBox(
              maxHeight: 650,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _audioFile.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var data = _audioFile[index];
                  return AudioWaveFormsWidget(path: data);
                },
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _buildText(),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_recordState == RecordState.stop) {
                      _start();
                    } else {
                      File? newFile = await _stop();
                     setState((){ _audioFile.add(newFile!);});
                    }
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          side: BorderSide.none))),
                  child: _buildStopAndPlayIcon(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:audio_waveforms/audio_waveforms.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioWaveFormsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final File path;

  //final PlayerController playerController1;

  const AudioWaveFormsWidget({Key? key, required this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioWaveFormsWidget> createState() => _AudioWaveFormsWidgetState();
}

class _AudioWaveFormsWidgetState extends State<AudioWaveFormsWidget> {
  late final PlayerController playerController1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    playerController1 = PlayerController()
      ..addListener(() {
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
      });
    _preparePlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _preparePlayer() async {
    bool exist = await widget.path.exists();
    if (exist) {
      playerController1.preparePlayer(widget.path.path);
    }
    print("--------------------------------${playerController1.bufferData}");
  }

  void _playOrPausePlayer(PlayerController controller) async {
    debugPrint(
        '****************************************${controller.playerState.toString()}');
    controller.playerState == PlayerState.playing
        ? await controller.pausePlayer()
        : await controller.startPlayer(finishMode: FinishMode.pause);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _playOrPausePlayer(playerController1);
                  },
                  icon: playerController1.playerState == PlayerState.playing
                      ? const Icon(Icons.pause)
                      : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
              AudioFileWaveforms(
                  density: 1.0,
                  enableSeekGesture: true,
                  size: const Size(100.0, 70.0),
                  playerController: playerController1),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? 
I have the same issue this displaying player waveforms.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to record, try setting the bitRate to 48000 (worked for me on iOS when it wasn't showing the waveforms when recording).

```dart
final RecorderController recorderController = RecorderController()
    ..androidEncoder = AndroidEncoder.aac
    ..androidOutputFormat = AndroidOutputFormat.mpeg4
    ..iosEncoder = IosEncoder.kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
    ..sampleRate = 44100
    ..bitRate = 48000;
```